# How does the Blazor compiler generate sequence numbers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compilation, blazor

The [Blazor Component Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#sequence-numbers-relate-to-code-line-numbers-and-not-execution-order) advises that constant sequence numbers be used when building a custom `RenderTree`:

> Generating the sequence numbers has lost all the useful information about where the if/else branches and loops were present in the original code. This results in a diff twice as long as before. ... In more realistic cases with complex and deeply nested structures, and especially with loops, the performance cost is more severe. Instead of immediately identifying which loop blocks or branches have been inserted or removed, the diff algorithm has to recurse deeply into the render trees and usually build far longer edit scripts because it is misinformed about how the old and new structures relate to each other.

So how does the Blazor compiler determine the sequence values for enumerated elements (i.e. elements repeated in a loop), given that the size of a collection cannot be determined at compile-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how the Blazor compiler compiles .razor file with code defining a table element. Note that all the elements added inside a cycle have the  **same sequence number**

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.OpenElement(0, "table");
                builder.OpenElement(1, "tbody");

                for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++)
                {
                    builder.OpenElement(2, "tr");
                    for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                    {
                        builder.OpenElement(3, "td");
                        builder.AddAttribute(4, "class", "tictactoe-cell");
                        builder.CloseElement();
                    }

                    builder.CloseElement();
                }

                builder.CloseElement();
                builder.CloseElement();
            }
        }
```

I'd suggest you define a simple component with some text ("Blazor!"), and instantiate it dynamically in another component, the number of times the user enter into a textbox. Run and see if it works. Now go to the .g.cs file produced by the compiler and see what the compiler initially produced. Come and tell us about your experiment.

Your question is very important, and a proficiency of it is essential when we want to create, as for instance, a menu component based on data retrieved from a database, list of searched profile results, etc.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Interesting, now I think I'd like to do some more digging to see just how these sequence numbers affect rendering.  The documentation made them seem like a sort of primary key for elements in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

> how does the Blazor compiler determine the sequence values

That is trivial. It simply does `seq++`, but it does that in the code generator, not embedded in that generated code.

So when you want to build a render tree dynamically, you need something else. Like using the linenumbers, as that articel suggests.

Comment: For normal generation sure, but how does this work with regards to collections?  Surely elements representing an item from the collection do not share their sequence number with other items?

Comment: Yes they do. Look up the .g.cs file for the WeatherForecast for example. Each 'row' gets the same static ids. That is what the diff engine wants.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic... but the sequence numbers in Blazor, at least Razor components, are line numbers. When 'compiling' the Razor component down to C# a class inheriting from ComponentBase is generated with a corresponding implementation of BuildRenderTree, as shown in the previous answer. The sequence numbers will correspond to the line number to where an ui element was found in the Razor file.